# Is it possible to control Kibana search via URL?

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, kibana

We have set up ELK stack to store our system log messages. Each operation and each error in the system have associated GUID, so in order to find all messages related to a certain activity we only need to obtain its respective ID or the ID of an error in case activity failed. What we can't figure out is how we can make it easy for users to retrieve information from Kibana if they have activity or error ID. Kibana Web UI is not REST, so it looks like there is no way to control Kibana search via URL, something that would be great for us so we could simply embed incident URL in error description.

Is there any way to approach such task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search via URL, you can use scripted dashboard instead. For example, in your case it would be something like :

localhost:9292/index.html#/dashboard/**script/logstash.js**?query=GUID  (Replace GUID with the id you are looking for)

Check out "More complex scripted dashboards" section of this documentation:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/kibana-3-milestone-4/

Comment: Thank you, this what we needed!